# Updating Table with Interval visits based on other table's start and end date

Tags: ms-access

I designed an MS Access app for our maintenance department to control the visit schedule.

I have 2 main tables:

1. Project data (Project name, no of visits, contract start date, end date, amount, etc...)
2. PPM (no of visit, scheduled date of the visit and visit type)

Currently we are adding the data on the new project in the first table, and then we are updating the second table with the dates Manual. e.g. if I have a project start on 01/01/2017 and it will end on 31/12/2017 and we have to conduct 4 visits (Quarterly). So we are updating the 2nd table as the following:

```
Visit no 1 02/01/2017 Quarterly Visit
Visit no 2 04/01/2017 Quarterly Visit
Visit no 3 07/01/2017 Quarterly Visit
Visit no 2 10/01/2017 Quarterly Visit
```

This to be able to get a schedule report.

The question is: can I have a way to fill the 2nd table (PPM) automatically based on start date and end date and no of visits of each contract?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, requires VBA code. Something like this:

```
Sub CreatePPM(dteStart As Date, dteEnd As Date, strType As String)
Dim x As Integer, dteVisit As Date
dteVisit = dteStart
Select Case strType
    Case "Quarterly"
        'code here
    Case "Daily"
        While dteVisit <= dteEnd
            CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO PPM(VisitNo, VisitDate, VisitType) Values(" & x & ", #" & dteVisit & "#, 'Daily')"
            dteVisit = dteVisit + 1
        Wend
End Select
End Sub
```

Modify code as required to handle different visit types. I have to say coding for the Quarterly type does seem to be challenging.

Then figure out what event to put the code into. Perhaps a button click or AfterUpdate event of Project data entry form. Will probably need additional code to make sure records are not entered multiple times.

When you develop code and have specific issue, post question.